# What does the MCP4725 Power-On-Reset (POR) value indicate?

Tags: mcp4725, power-on-reset

I managed to read from an [MCP4725](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/22039c-78124.pdf) using I2C. In the second byte below, the POR value it gives me is '1' (the whole byte is `11000000`)

[image: I2C POR 2nd byte]

I know that if `RDY/BSY = 1`, it means the device is ready to write its EEPROM.

When does `POR = 0`? What does it mean if `POR = 1`?

The datasheet gives no information about the value of POR. I think that `POR = 1` when the IC's power is >2V and `POR = 0` when IC's power is <2V. (But if that is the case, giving me the POR value has no meaning)

EDIT:

Based on the below section of the datasheet, since there is a "after POR" state, I think `POR=1` means that the device has "completely woken up from its power-up/reset state and its ready to receive commands".

[image: AFTER POR]

Since after the reset, the device loads the data from EEPROM to the register (to output its analog value,) this takes some time, and while `POR = 0`, this event is still taking place.

Am I right?

Comment: *The device can be reset by two independent events: (a) by POR or (b) by I2C General Call Reset Command.* - might it inform you what the event was that caused it?

Comment: Well, I did not do the General Call reset, so the Power was the one that Resetted the device. Hmm If I use the general call reset, will POR be 0 after that? I will try that.

Comment: It's worth a shot.